# Response from server and data accepting multiple models

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have problem with understand how works interfaces in typescript.
I have response like this

```js
"page": 1,
"pageSize": 250,
"count": 250,
"totalCount": 15851
"data": [...]
```

and my data model changes depending on the query.
Once is

```js
data: ICard[];
```

and next time, e.g

```js
data: ISets[];
```

how to properly build an interface to handle subsequent cases. Only the data changes.
My model

```js
export interface Response {
  count: number;
  data: ICard[];
  page: number;
  pageSize: number;
  totalCount: number;
}
```

Comment: Just make 2 functions with different return types, one for each type of query... If for some reason the return type is totally random (which would be really weird), you'll need some type checking. If you want ppl to be able to give a more accurate answer, you'll need to give some info about the endpoint(s).

Comment: I was thinking about something like this
`data: ICard[] | ISets[] | ... ;`

Comment: If you really want to handle both in one function (which I do not recommend), you can do typechecking with an if statement: `if (result typeof ICard) { ... }` etc. Again, if you want better help, you'll need to tell us something more about the endpoint(s) / your API you want to talk to.

Comment: I am trying to implement the model https://docs.pokemontcg.io/getting-started/migration with data structure. I must show cards, sets etc

Comment: I don't see the issue, cards and sets have totally different endpoints `/v2/cards` & `/v2/sets` ... one returns `ICard[]` and the other `ISets[]`. If you are looking for an example on how to use the HttpClient, you can find it [here](https://angular.io/guide/http).

Comment: i know but `onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {
    this.cardData$ = this.http
      .get<Response>('https://api.pokemontcg.io/v2/cards')
      .pipe(map((response) => response.data));
  }` 
`public cardData$!: Observable<ICard[]>;`

in this case in Response interface i have `data: ICard[]` but how set data: ISets[] to http.get - /v2/sets ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252541/discussion-between-kamillopl-and-h3ar7b3a7).

Comment: Just replace `Response` with the model of the expected return... I really recommend giving angulars [Tou of Heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes) a try. The part 'Get data from a server' covers all of this.